# Import of modules in TypeScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I have 2 typescript files,
first app.ts file input point
and the second mobiles.ts file the module contains interfaces and classes
System of modules CommonJS, an ECMAScript version ES5 is set.

When I run app, in browser get error

> ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at app.js:2

**contents of the file mobiles.ts**

```
export interface Device {
    model: string;
    company: string;
    displayInfo(): void;
}

export class Smartphone implements Device {
    model: string;
    company: string;

    displayInfo(): void {
        console.log(`Smartphone. Model: ${this.model} - Company: ${this.company}`);
    }
}

export class Tablet implements Device {
    model: string;
    company: string;

    displayInfo(): void {
        console.log(`Tablet. Model: ${this.model} - Company: ${this.company}`);
    }
}
```

**contents of the file app.ts**

```
import {Smartphone} from "./mobiles";

window.onload = () => {
    let mi: Smartphone = new Smartphone();
    mi.company = "Xiaomi";
    mi.model = "RedMi 4 Pro";
    mi.displayInfo();
};
```

**After a compilation contents of the file mobiles.js**

```
"use strict";
var Smartphone = (function () {
    function Smartphone() {
    }
    Smartphone.prototype.displayInfo = function () {
        console.log("Smartphone. Model: " + this.model + " - Company: " + this.company);
    };
    return Smartphone;
}());
exports.Smartphone = Smartphone;
var Tablet = (function () {
    function Tablet() {
    }
    Tablet.prototype.displayInfo = function () {
        console.log("Tablet. Model: " + this.model + " - Company: " + this.company);
    };
    return Tablet;
}());
exports.Tablet = Tablet;
//# sourceMappingURL=mobiles.js.map
```

**After a compilation contents of the file app.js**

```
"use strict";
var mobiles_1 = require("./mobiles"); //Error Get here
window.onload = function () {
    var mi = new mobiles_1.Smartphone();
    mi.company = "Xiaomi";
    mi.model = "RedMi 4 Pro";
    mi.displayInfo();
};
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use angular2 native lifecycle hooks instead of `window.onload` in the `app.ts` file.

Comment: In the project it isn't used Angular 2